# How to re-order strings that are separated by a comma?

Tags: r, regex, string

```
patterns <- c("Athens, Greece", "New York, New York, USA", "Georgia,USA", "Southern California,    USA ")
```

I have a collection of strings in `patterns`, and I would like to only focus on those that have a single comma. For example, the string `New York, New York, USA` should be discarded. I tried the following regular expression to find the strings that only have 1 comma but it didn't work.

```
grep(",{1}", patterns)
> [1] 1 2 3 4
```

My ultimate goal is to re-order these strings, so that the final output looks something like this: the string after the comma shows up first, comma is removed, and excess spaces are deleted

```
final_output 
> [1] "Greece Athens"  "USA Georgia"  "USA Southern California"
```

Comment: A couple function recommendations,`stringr::str_count()` for counting commas, `stringr::str_squish()` for removing reducing whitespace within a string.

Comment: `sub("([^,]+), *([^,]+)$|.*", "\\2 \\1", patterns)`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex:

```r
patterns <- c("Athens, Greece", "New York, New York, USA", 
              "Georgia,USA", "Southern California,    USA ")

grep("^[^,]*,[^,]*$", patterns)
#> [1] 1 3 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Explanation:

1. `^[^,]*` searches any character but a comma, starting at the beginning of the string;
2. `,` a literal comma;
3. `[^,]*$` followed by anything but a comma until the end of the string;
4. combined, the above search one comma only, with no other commas before or after it.

Index by `grep`'s result or use argument `value`.

```r
grep("^[^,]*,[^,]*$", patterns, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "Athens, Greece"               "Georgia,USA"                 
#> [3] "Southern California,    USA "
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

As for the second goal, here is a way. Once again, base R only.

```r
patterns <- c("Athens, Greece", "New York, New York, USA", 
              "Georgia,USA", "Southern California,    USA ", "This That")

v <- grep("^[^,]*,[^,]*$", patterns, value = TRUE)
sapply(strsplit(v, ","), \(x) paste(trimws(rev(x)), collapse = " "))
#> [1] "Greece Athens"           "USA Georgia"            
#> [3] "USA Southern California"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gregexpr()` to see how many commas in the strings.

```r
n.comma <- sapply(gregexpr(',', patterns), \(x) sum(x > 0))
n.comma
# [1] 1 2 1 1
```

For your second goal:

```r
sub('(.+)\\s*,\\s*(.+)', '\\2 \\1', trimws(patterns)[n.comma == 1])

# [1] "Greece Athens"   "USA Georgia"   "USA Southern California"
```

Comment: For the first part, why does `lengths(gregexpr(',', "country"))` also return 1 when there's no comma in the string?

Comment: @Adrian because `gregexpr` will return `-1` if there is no match. I edit the code to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex free version - if you want to remove those with more than one comma, then this combination of using `str_count` and `str_trim` will work:

```
library(stringr)
res = str_split(patterns[str_count(patterns, ",") < 2], ",", simplify=T)

str_trim(paste(res[,2], res[,1], sep=" "))
```

```
[1] "Greece Athens"           "USA Georgia"            
[3] "USA Southern California"
```

Answer (score 1):

First find out strings that have exactly one comma and use that to extract relevant strings in `patterns`. Then capture all characters before AND after the comma into two capture groups (note the brackets `()`). Then replace the string with the second capture group `\\2` followed by a space  , then the first capture group `\\1`.

```
library(stringr)

sub("^(\\w.+?),\\s*(\\w.+?)\\s{0,}$", 
    "\\2 \\1", 
    patterns[str_count(patterns, ",") == 1])

[1] "Greece Athens"           "USA Georgia"            
[3] "USA Southern California"
```

Answer (score 1):

in base R use `sub` as shown below:

```
sub("([^,]+), *([^,]+)$|.*", "\\2 \\1", trimws(patterns))

[1] "Greece Athens"           " "                      
[3] "USA Georgia"             "USA Southern California"
```

If you need to drop the empty values:

```
grep("\\w", sub("([^,]+), *([^,]+)$|.*", "\\2 \\1", trimws(patterns)), value = TRUE)

[1] "Greece Athens"           "USA Georgia"             "USA Southern California"
```